How can I ignore invalid data when casting to timestamp type?
I have a table who has a column timestamp which type is text. Most of the rows have timestamp format as 2024-10-13T00:00:00.000Z. But there are some rows have invalid timestamp value.
When I use this date_trunc to aggregate the timestamp,
select date_trunc('hour', timestamp_candidate::timestamp) hourly

I got this error:

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "xxxxxx"

The invalid value could be anything including null. Is there a way to skip any invalid values?

Also related: PostgreSQL alternative to SQL Server’s try_cast function

Confusing… Is your column of type timestamp or type text? It cannot be both. If timestamp, which one exactly: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE or TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE?

@Filburt Only the first example in the first thread shows how to skip them (not very efficiently) otherwise both discuss try_cast() type of thing that gives you a default rather than skip the mismatch.

It's tempting to tag [regex] just to add an example showing a mile-long convoluted pattern that still requires a case to switch to a different one based on current_setting('DateStyle'), and still doesn't quite replicate PostgreSQL internal logic.

@Filburt pg_input_is_valid() can validate the data type, no need to write your own function.

@FrankHeikens I admit my research for existing answers was biased by the respective TSQL methods I'd use in such a case.

In PostgreSQL 16 and above, there's pg_input_is_valid():
demo at db<>fiddle
select timestamp_candidate
      ,timestamp_candidate::timestamp
      ,date_trunc('hour', (timestamp_candidate)::timestamp) hourly
from your_table
where pg_input_is_valid(timestamp_candidate,'timestamp');




timestamp_candidateit's type text
timestamp_candidateas timestamp
hourlynote Special Date/Time Inputs are valid




2024-12-13 12:00
2024-12-13 12:00:00
2024-12-13 12:00:00


2024-12-13 07:41:18.196153+00
2024-12-13 07:41:18.196153
2024-12-13 07:00:00


2024-12-13
2024-12-13 00:00:00
2024-12-13 00:00:00


today allballs
2024-12-13 00:00:00
2024-12-13 00:00:00


epoch
1970-01-01 00:00:00
1970-01-01 00:00:00


infinity
infinity
infinity


-infinity
-infinity
-infinity


now
2024-12-13 07:41:18.196153
2024-12-13 07:00:00


today
2024-12-13 00:00:00
2024-12-13 00:00:00


tomorrow
2024-12-14 00:00:00
2024-12-14 00:00:00


yesterday
2024-12-12 00:00:00
2024-12-12 00:00:00



Here's what it skipped over. Thing to note is that a text literal 'null' isn't considered a valid input that would lead to a timestamp-typed field with a null in it and a regular null yields null rather than true or false even though null::timestamp works fine.



rejected
pg_input_is_valid




not_a_timestamp
f


another thing that is not a timestamp
f


null
null


null
f


allballs (it's a midnight that's missing a date)
f



From the doc:

pg_input_is_valid ( string text, type text ) → boolean
Tests whether the given string is valid input for the specified data type, returning true or false.
This function will only work as desired if the data type's input function has been updated to report invalid input as a “soft” error. Otherwise, invalid input will abort the transaction, just as if the string had been cast to the type directly.
pg_input_is_valid('42', 'integer') → t
pg_input_is_valid('42000000000', 'integer') → f
pg_input_is_valid('1234.567', 'numeric(7,4)') → f


In PostgreSQL 15 and earlier, you can build your own:
create or replace function is_interpretable_as(arg text, arg_type text) 
returns boolean language plpgsql as $$
begin
    execute format('select cast(%L as %s)', arg, arg_type);
    return true;
exception when others then
    return false;
end $$;

Note that this will return false regardless of whether the argument or the type is invalid, or both. Unlike pg_input_is_valid(), it yields true for null, considering it a valid input for any type.

Postgres does not have a corresponding function to Sql Server's try_cast() function. But it is a simple matter to create a specific implementation (in this case for timestamp). The following is one such example: (see demo)
create or replace function is_valid_timestamp(timestamp_candidate text)
   returns timestamp 
  language plpgsql
  strict
as $$
  begin 
      return timestamp_candidate::timestamp;
  exception 
      when invalid_datetime_format then return null;
  end;
$$;

Note: The function is susceptible to your datestyle setting.
